# Oozie workflow import fails

Tags: hadoop, oozie, cloudera-cdh, oozie-coordinator, oozie-workflow

I am working on Oozie to automate ETL which involves more than 100 steps.I am able to create the workflow successfully in the development cluster.The problem comes when I am trying to move this huge workflow using export and import feature of Hue. I am getting a weird(Pardon my ignorance) error while importing workflows. Exports are working fine.

```
{"message": "Problem installing fixture '/tmp/tmp31Ptfm.json': Document2 matching query does not exist."}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like Hue is just as useless now as it was in 2015. My 2 cents: use Hue as an "Oozie IDE" if you can, but don't try to export the Hue-specific "project" file -- export the **Workflow** (+ Coordinator) XML script(s) that was actually submitted to Oozie in your tests. That XML is your "executable" that can be rolled-out to Test / Prod via Oozie command-line (or REST API).

Comment: Thanks! I am aware of this alternative but let's just say that this will not solve my problem.

Comment: unfortunately you cannot export workflow.xml with hue since 3.9

Answer (score 0):

Document2 refers to RDBMS table backing Hue.

The "matching query" that's missing refers to a Hive script, for example, that you've not exported/imported and your workflow references.

But I agree with above comment - Store your XML and properties in source control... Use CI/CD to roll updates across multiple environments